# Android show on lock screen with Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In Android (and Titanium),

I need a Window shows on Locked screen.

I found a solution making a Activity with FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED on Titanium module, and it's working fine.

But can I do this using Titanium code? (I mean using java script code)

I'm using Titanium SDK 5.1.2 and How can I shows a single Window (i.e. created by Ti.UI.createWindow or any others) appears over the lock screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can set flags on Titanium Window activities via the [windowFlags](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-windowFlags) property. You'd have to pass the [constant value](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED) because Titanium does have a proxy for that constant.

I'm not sure if this would even work for Titanium Windows, but you can try.

If it doesn't work this might make a great feature request. Please check if it has already been requested at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it has not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide a complete description in the ticket. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.